# Merging different Networks and give them different colors

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I have 11 different networks (UN) which I want to merge. I want that every node in one network should be represented by same color, different color from other networks, so that I can identify that which interaction belongs to which network. I am using following code for merging networks one by one.

```
graph.union.by.name = function(g1, g2)
{
stopifnot(is.directed(g1) & is.directed(g2))
dv1 = get.vertices.as.data.frame(g1)
dv2 = get.vertices.as.data.frame(g2)
de1 = get.edges.as.data.frame(g1)
de2 = get.edges.as.data.frame(g2)
dv = safer.merge(dv1, dv2, all=TRUE)
de = safer.merge(de1, de2, all=TRUE)
g  = graph.data.frame(de, directed=FALSE, vertices=dv)
return(g)
}
graph.union.by.name(g1,g2)
```

1. `get.edges.as.data.frame`: This function return graph edges as a mergable data.frame
2. `graph.union.by.name`: This function create union of two graphs. This function correctly unions the graphs based on the name attributes, such that: Any vertex that is in g1 or g2 is in the resultAny edge that is in g1 or g2 is in the result.
3. `get.vertices.as.data.frame`: This function return graph vertices as a data.frame
4. `safer.merge`: This function checks some very basic pitfalls that can cause incorrect merge results, and then merges using the merge function.

My questions are:

1. 1: How to add the colors in networks so that I can identify each
   interaction (FYI: There are some nodes and interaction which are
   common among these networks)?
2. 2: Eventually I have to compare (or merge) this final network (comprises of 11 merged networks) with an other network (let's say network X) and I want to know with which network in the merged network, the network X has most similarity.
3. 3: Is it possible to make a directed network and do the above analysis. If Yes, then the directed network will contain the information of nodes interaction like this: `node A --> node B` (This means node A activates node B) OR `node A --| node B` (This means node A inhibits node B)`. So is it possible to add this information in networks as well? Currently for the sake of simplicity I am considering the Undirected networks but my eventual aim is to consider the Directed ones.

Example:

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.formula(a-b-c)
g2 <- graph.formula(b-c-d)
graph.union.by.name(g1,g2)
```

I want nodes of `g1` and `g2` be of different color and then I will apply it with different colors for all of my networks.